# Problem in Taylor series expansion using Recursion

Tags: c++, recursion, taylor-series

I have written the following code to find the Taylor series summation using recursion. Although I am getting correct results but my problem is with the **static variable s** (declared in code and assigned value 1) whatever may be the value of s
I choose output comes out to be same in Code-Blocks IDE which I am using .

```
   #include<iostream>
using namespace std;
double e(int x, int n)
{
 static double s=1;
 if(n==0)
 return s;
 s=1+x*s/n;
 return e(x,n-1);

}
int main(){
cout<<e(5,100);
}
```

Can you explain how is this happening?

Comment: Pick some starting values that only result in a couple of recursions. Then use a debugger to step through your code, and step into the recursive calls. That should help you see what's happening and hopefully help you figure out the problem.

Comment: And you say you get the correct result, so what is the problem more exactly? If you get the correct result from the initial call (`e(5, 100)`) then you don't have a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of a math "problem" than a C one and it's due to the numerical stability of the sequence

```
sn = 1 + x * sn + 1 / n
```

used in the body of your function.

Consider the following table, where some of the `n` values of `s` are showed, for different starting points (0.1, 1, 10, 100) and `x = 5`:

```
=======================================================
                              s
   n     0.100000    1.000000   10.000000  100.000000
-------------------------------------------------------
  100    1.005000    1.050000    1.500000    6.000000
   99    1.050758    1.053030    1.075758    1.303030
   98    1.053610    1.053726    1.054886    1.066481
   97    1.054310    1.054316    1.054376    1.054973
   96    1.054912    1.054912    1.054915    1.054947
   95    1.055522    1.055522    1.055522    1.055524
   94    1.056145    1.056145    1.056145    1.056145
   93    1.056782    1.056782    1.056782    1.056782
  ...    ...         ...         ...         ...
   10    1.877638    1.877638    1.877638    1.877638
    9    2.043132    2.043132    2.043132    2.043132
    8    2.276958    2.276958    2.276958    2.276958
    7    2.626398    2.626398    2.626398    2.626398
    6    3.188665    3.188665    3.188665    3.188665
    5    4.188665    4.188665    4.188665    4.188665
    4    6.235832    6.235832    6.235832    6.235832
    3   11.393053   11.393053   11.393053   11.393053
    2   29.482632   29.482632   29.482632   29.482632
    1  148.413159  148.413159  148.413159  148.413159
-------------------------------------------------------
```